# How use Maple12 to solve a differential equation by using Euler's method?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, maple

Consider the differential equation $y^{\prime}=y-2$ with initial condition $y\left(0\right)=1$.

a) Use Euler's method with 4 steps of size 0.2 to estimate $y\left(0.8\right)$

I know how to do this by hand; however, I have maple 12 installed and was trying to figure out how to do this with Maple, and then make a graph showing each step of the function.  Any suggestions.  I have tried looking on mapleprimes, but it keeps pointing me to functions for newer versions of maplesoft, which I don't have.

I posted this question to use as a model, because I have solved this problem by hand and it will help me edited it for other differential equations.

ps. I hope this is the proper place to ask this question, if not please tell me where would be a better place.

Comment: you are welcome.use  this and also another site which i have posted as answer.good lucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this would help  ,just change initially condition  and  step size
http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~hanson/MAPLE/euler.html

i am not sure that is is for maple12,but i think commands would be same,just try it and if there is  errors,post here
use also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Comment: yea, it failed on dsolve. going to check the help and post it on stackoverflow/questions. Thanks for your reference.

Comment: so it means that some  commands are basicaly  changed or maybe  some errors on site,good lucks my friend

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. [Lesson 14: Euler's Method](http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=1405)

Comment: great my friend.good lucks.two site  mathematics and  stackoverflow is great  place for  combine mathematic and programming +1